# 7za compress batch of files using deflate compression

Tags: windows, command-line

this is the command that i used to compress a folder under windows

```
for %f in (*.au) do 7za.exe -tgzip %~nf.gz %f -mx=9
```

But 7za says that the command is incorrect during each iteration

this is the error message

```
7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18


Error:
Incorrect command line
```

How can i correct this?

Answer (score 0):

In my own batch script, I use `%%f` instead of `%f` like e.g.:

```
for /R "D:\MyFolder" %%f in (*.au) do (call "D:\sfk165.exe" split 200m "%%f")
```

Maybe this works for you, too?

Comment: in batch files you have to use %%f instead of %f. %f is for commands when entered directly on command line.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know. Could it then be that you have to enclose it in quotes, in case the file name has white spaces?